# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my setup (boiled down). I have a "layout function":

```
  struct LayoutFunc {
    LayoutFunc( int limit , int value ) { lim.push_back(limit); val.push_back(value); }
    //LayoutFunc(LayoutFunc&& func) : lim(func.lim),val(func.val) {}
    LayoutFunc(const LayoutFunc& func) : lim(func.lim),val(func.val) {} // error: std::bad_alloc
    LayoutFunc(const std::vector<int>& lim_, 
               const std::vector<int>& val_ ) : lim(lim_),val(val_) {}
    LayoutFunc curry( int limit , int value ) const {
      std::vector<int> rlim(lim);
      std::vector<int> rval(val);
      rlim.push_back(limit);
      rval.push_back(value);
      LayoutFunc ret(rlim,rval);
      return ret;
    };
    std::vector<int> lim;
    std::vector<int> val;
  };
```

Then I have a class that uses `LayoutFunc`:

```
template<class T> class A
{
public:
  A( const LayoutFunc& lf_ ) : lf(lf_), member( lf.curry(1,0) ) {}
  A(const A& a): lf(lf), member(a.function) {}  // corresponds to line 183 in real code
private:
  LayoutFunc lf;
  T member;
};
```

The order of data members is correct. There are more types like `class A` which use slightly different numbers to "curry" the layout function. I don't print them here to save space (they have the same structure, only different numbers). At the end I use something like:

```
A< B< C<int> > > a( LayoutFunc(1,0) );
```

which would build the "curried" layout function according to the template type order.

Now, probably this simple (boiled down) example works. However, in my real application at runtime I get a `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` in the copy constructor of `LayoutFunc`.

I think there is a flaw in the setup that has to do with taking a reference to a temporary and this temporary is destroyed before the consumer (in this case the copy constructor of `LayoutFunc`) uses it. This would explain `lim(func.lim),val(func.val)` to fail. But I can't see where the flaw is especially because `curry` returns a true `lvalue`. Also I tried it with the move constructor and compiled in c++11 mode. Same behaviour.

Here the backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6437445 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimised out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff643abab in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#2  0x00007ffff6caa69d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff6ca8846 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff6ca8873 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff6ca896e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff6c556a2 in std::__throw_bad_alloc() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00000000004089f6 in allocate (__n=18446744073709551592, this=0x7fffffffdaf8) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/ext/new_allocator.h:90
#8  _M_allocate (__n=18446744073709551592, this=0x7fffffffdaf8) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:150
#9  _Vector_base (__a=..., __n=18446744073709551592, this=0x7fffffffdaf8) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:123
#10 vector (__x=..., this=0x7fffffffdaf8) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:279
#11 LayoutFunc (func=..., this=0x7fffffffdae0) at layoutfunc.h:17
#12 A (a=..., this=0x7fffffffdad0) at A.h:183
```

A.h:183 is the copy constructor of `A`:

```
  A(const A& a): lf(lf), member(a.function) {}
```

Comment: `bad_alloc` exceptions are usually a sign that an allocation filed. Have you checked your free memory?

Comment: can you post what is PScalarJIT?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is lack of available memory. In the BT you can see that the `std::vector<int>` allocation fails. This is probably because it wants to do something incorrect.

Comment: It seems your OS is having trouble recruiting 18446744073709551592 bytes(~17179869183 GiB) of free memory. [Download more RAM](http://downloadmoreram.com/). Or allocate less?

Answer (score 3):

```
A(const A& a): lf(lf), member(a.function) {}
```

should be

```
A(const A& a): lf(a.lf), member(a.function) {}
```

BЈовић comment pointed me in the direction to find this bug. if you post an answer, +1  BЈовић. Also +1 for sehe to make understand BT